# Highlight clicked/tapped element in Ionic Framework

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm working with Ionic Framework. How could I show `background-color` change or similar when an item is tapped on mobile? All the states (active, focus etc) below are not displaying if you just tap the item, but will show if you hold down your finger. This is not wanted behaviour as it doesn't really indicate to the user that he/she has tapped an element and something should happen (ie. view should change/is about to change).

CSS:

```
.item-thumbnail-right {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.item-thumbnail-right:active,
.item-thumbnail-right:focus,
.item-thumbnail-right.active {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item item-thumbnail-right">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="img" src="img.jpg"></div>
  </div>
  <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
  <p>Text lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Should I use Ionics `on-tap` directive to add a class and show the different `background-color` accordingly? I should then probably also remove the class at some point if it stays in the view cache.

Comment: have you tried `:hover` ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had tried `:hover` also but it didn't work. Seems like I just had the "active" class wrong. Ionic adds `activated` class to a clicked/tapped element which I can use to get the wanted effect. I made this to an answer so that it might help someone in the future since I couldn't find the answer myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like I had the `active` class wrong. Ionic adds a class `activated` in the item clicked/tapped so what I was trying works, but the class needs to be `activated` like this:

```
.item-thumbnail-right {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.item-thumbnail-right.activated {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```